# Is it possible to execute some logic(API call) before the angular router init?

Tags: angular, api, asynchronous, router

I'm working on a multi-domain website. I want to change the default route URL based on the domain. Is that possible in angular without having a service or module check it and redirecting after Init?

I want to store the default URL In the database behind an API call. The API call is already used for loading the right CSS and other side specific configurations. Which means I have to wait for the API call to finish first.

#### Example:

> https://example.com --> angular defaultRoute https://example.com/nl/home

> https://information.com --> angular defaultRoute https://information.com/nl/welcome

Kind regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `APP_INITIALIZER` in your module, and do some checks before the application starts if that is what you are looking for.

`APP_INITIALIZER` does support an `async` call, so if you need to do some asynchronous operations the application will wait for the async operation to resolve before loading the application.

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => () => {
        if (/* some condition */) {
          window.location.href = 'https://example.com/nl/home'
        } else {
          window.location.href = 'https://information.com/nl/welcome'
        }
      },
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```